# iPad app icon doesn't appear in organizer

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this question has been asked a lot but I can't solve it. All icon files are in the correct dimensions and in the right place. When I archive the app the icon is just white in organizer. What am I suppose to do or can I add the icon later in itunes connect so it will still have when it's submitted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you your image asset catalog has all the files in the right dimension for iphone, ipad, spotlight etc, you should not care about the icon shown in organizer. The icons will appear in place in the app. In itunesconnect you have to upload a 1024x1024 app icon.

Comment: Thank you but what is the image asset catalog?

Comment: 5, but I found it. But will it work if I have the correct icons in the info.plist file instead of using asset catalog?

Comment: To submit to the App store and support iOS 7 you have to move your images to the asset catalog. It is pretty easy.